# График с заливкой относительно начала координат

Tags: python, numpy, графика, matplotlib

Задача: построить стандартный график с заливкой относительно начала координат (больше 0 - один цвет, меньше - другой).

Есть два массива:
x - со значениями от 1 до 27 (всего 27):

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0]
```

y - со значениями `float` (0.0 - 10.0) (всего 27):

```
[-0.9, -4.6, -5.9, -1.3, -0.4, 3.8, 2.6, 2.0, 5.4, 4.8, 3.2, -6.8, -4.6, -1.0, 2.2, 1.0, 2.9, 1.5, -5.6, -3.0, -3.5, -2.1, -2.3, -1.9, -0.9, 6.1, 8.0]
```

```
data = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])

x = data[0]
y = data[4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y > 0, color="red")
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y < 0, color="blue")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Как мне изменить код, чтобы избежать следующей ошибки?

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: "есть два массива" - где они есть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Суть ошибки в том, что операторы сравнения не переопределены для списков. А для `Numpy.NDArray` они переопределены и будут работать именно так, как вы и предполагали в вашем коде.

Поэтому преобразуйте списки `x` и `y` в `numpy` массивы:

```
x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
```

далее ваш код:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y > 0, color="red")
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=y < 0, color="blue")
plt.grid(True)
```

---

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]